# Python. Finding thresholds for rows of data

Tags: python, math, data-analysis

[image]

I'm a novice in Python but I have to solve the following task. Please help me.

I have two very-very long lists of data. For each list, I have to find a threshold which would divide list on the values -1 (below threshold) and +1 (above threshold). I need to divide both rows for the purpose of finding the best possible correlation between two sets of data. It has to be something like this:

```
List1 List2     List1 After Threshold applying  List2 After Threshold applying 
-50      -300     -1                             -1
-40      -200     -1                             -1
-30      -100     -1                             -1
-20      0        -1                             -1
-10      100       1                              1
0        200       1                              1
1        300       1                              1
2        400       1                              1
```

So, in my example threshold for `list1` would be -10 (everything below it is equal to -1, everything above is equal to 1) and a threshold for `list2` would be 100.

Many thanks!

Comment: You are damn confusing man..... Try learn Python syntax and datatypes. It will help.

Comment: Try numpy's median: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.median.html

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I have to explain that my work is very far from Python, but this task has happened to me unexpectedly. So far I opened my file in Python and, I think, I have to do something with Loops, but what?

Comment: I also created Error matrices using both Average and Median values of the rows as thresholds. It gave me User's and Producer's accuracy about 0.70 (for Average is a little bit better than for the Median).

Answer (score 1):

Look into the python package `pandas`. Here's a tutorial: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = [-50, -40, -30, -20, -10, 0, 1, 2]
list2 = [-300, -200, -100, 0, 100, 200, 300, 400]

df = pd.DataFrame({'List 1': list1, 'List 2': list2})

newdf = df.copy()
newdf[df > df.median()] = 1
newdf[df < df.median()] = -1
```

`newdf` now contains the following:

```
   List 1  List 2
0      -1      -1
1      -1      -1
2      -1      -1
3      -1      -1
4       1       1
5       1       1
6       1       1
7       1       1
```

If you want both the new and old lists side by side, you can concatenate the dataframes. It's also a good idea to rename the columns first:

```
# rename columns:    
newdf = newdf.rename(columns=lambda x: x + ' after threshold')
# concatenate dataframes:
result = pd.concat([df, newdf], axis=1)
```

With the following result:

```
   List 1  List 2  List 1 after threshold  List 2 after threshold
0     -50    -300                      -1                      -1
1     -40    -200                      -1                      -1
2     -30    -100                      -1                      -1
3     -20       0                      -1                      -1
4     -10     100                       1                       1
5       0     200                       1                       1
6       1     300                       1                       1
7       2     400                       1                       1
```